# Problem storing blob values with Doctrine

Tags: php, sql-server, doctrine, blob

I'm using Doctrine 1.1.2 as my ORM framework in combination with Zend Framework and a MSSQL server back-end. What I am trying to do is to store a blob to the database, but Doctrine is throwing me errors when I try. The column in the database is of type varbinary(max), and the model in Doctrine is configured as follows:

```
$this->hasColumn('binary_data', 'blob', null, array(
         'type' => 'blob',
         'notnull' => false,
         'primary' => false,
         'autoincrement' => false,
         ));
```

This is generated with Doctrine::generateModelsFromDB, and should be correct. The source of the blob is a file upload. I have verified that the file upload succeeds, and that I am able to print the binary data (shows as a bunch of garbled data).

When I try to save the binary data by using the Doctrine model, I get different error messages based on what I do. I have so far tried this (probably some more too that I don't remember):

```
// Error:SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 10007 Incorrect syntax near '%PDF-1.5 %µµµµ...
$model->binary_data = fread(fopen($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], 'r'), filesize($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]));
$model->save();
---
// Error: same as above
$fileHandle = fopen($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "r");
$fileContent = fread($fileHandle, filesize($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]));
$model->binary_data = $fileContent;
$model->save();
---
// This should work on 1.2, but I have 1.1.2
// Error: Validation failed in class Clazz 1 field had validation error: * 1 validator failed on binary_data (type)
$model->binary_data = file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
$model->save();
```

This should be straight forward, but I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [base64_encode-ing](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) your data prior to saving and [base64_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) it after you  pull it from the database.

Comment: Will that work with a varbinary column? That would result in string if I'm not mistaken. I could change the column to a varchar(max), but I would rather store it as a varbinary. I'll try it out and see what works. I just can't believe that it's not possible to store blobs into an mssql server with doctrine, so I would really like to see an example of how to do this ;)

Comment: You wrote: "The column in the database is of type varchar(max)" that's why I thought that there's trouble with the binary data. Check your schema, maybe you've got a typo on the column type and have been trying saving binary data into string column.

Comment: Oh sorry, the typo is in the text above. The column type is varbinary(max) in the database.